# TypeError: fit_resample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: scikit-learn, imbalanced-data, imblearn

Using `imblearn` for the imbalanced datasets, the parameters seems to have changed. I am using `undersampling.NearMiss`.
Here is the code:

```
from imblearn import under_sampling

balanced = under_sampling.NearMiss()
X_res, y_res = under_sampling.NearMiss.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Here is the error which it's throwing

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14792/1374027827.py in <module>
      2 
      3 balanced = under_sampling.NearMiss()
----> 4 X_res, y_res = under_sampling.NearMiss.fit_resample(X, y)

TypeError: fit_resample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the object you just defined.

This should do the trick:

```
from imblearn import under_sampling

balanced = under_sampling.NearMiss()
X_res, y_res = balanced.fit_resample(X, y)
```